# Do I need an NVidia GPU locally if I only sync projects to create remote builds on targets?

Tags: debian, nvidia, gpu, eclipse

I'll be installing the cuda toolkit 7.5 on debian stretch, currently without an nvidia card. I only intend to do [remote development](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/remote-application-development-nvidia-nsight-eclipse-edition/) (sync projects to create remote builds on targets) on an nvidia server with two titan blacks.

The [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#axzz43wd7tMFJ) says I need a cuda-capable gpu, but I'm wondering if it's really needed if I never build locally.

Has anyone tried this kind of install scenario?

If so, what do I need to do to get nsight for eclipse working to create, debug, and profile remote builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some newer information [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#remote-development) that says a gpu is not required for either **cross compilation mode** or **remote synchronized project mode**.

I've installed cuda toolkit 7.5 on linux mint 17.3 using the ubuntu 14.04 local deb file. The installer complained of the missing gpu but went through to completion otherwise.

In you're wondering, I gave up on debian because of issues with my usb wireless stick (yes, I used the non-free drivers, etc). Mint found it without a hitch.